# Counting substring or word in a string

Tags: python, string, count

I was wondering how, in python, I could count the occurrences of the word "the" in a string.
The problem I get is that it will count "the" in words like: there, theatre....etc

```
s = "The Journey: today I went there! There was not the...theatre but the Walgreens so I could buy a thermometer"

howmanythe = s.count("the") #I feel like here you could do " the " but I would miss any "the" after grammar notation
print("There are {} many the's in that phrase".format(howmanythe))
```

Sorry if my formating is bad, this is my first post.

Answer (score 2):

You may try a regex search on `\bthe\b`, in case insensitive mode, which will find all `the` words in the text:

```
s = "The Journey: today I went there! There was not the...theatre but the Walgreens so I could buy a thermometer"
num = len(re.findall(r'\bthe\b', s, flags=re.IGNORECASE))
print("There were " + str(num) + " 'the' words in the text")
```

This prints:

```
There were 3 'the' words in the text
```

Comment: Just don't forget to `import re` :)

Comment: @pitamer [I wouldn't forget that for the world :-)](https://rextester.com/TIKHB23088).